# Other HTML serialisations?

Tags: html, serialization

After keeping in mind that HTML has both an SGML and XML serialisations, which are just encodings for a parser to "explode" into a DOM, I'm wondering whether there are other serialisations for HTML. A JSON serialisation? If so, are there any parsers for these alternative serialisations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful serializations? No. Obviously, people can make up their own serializations, and given the size of the Web, there's probably a number of them. However, none of those are supported widely. For example, there's the format used by [html5lib tests](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/source/browse/testdata/tree-construction/tests1.dat), which is used for testing HTML5 parsing implementations.

(Also note that what you call the SGML serialization isn't really SGML at all, as noted in [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html).)